# Why does the error "Invalid index, array indices must be positive integers or logical values" occur when using silhouette(POINT, idx) in MatLab?

Tags: matlab

```
POINTS_LAT = {START_LAT; END_LAT};
POINTS_LNG = {START_LNG; END_LNG};
POINTS = [POINTS_LAT POINTS_LNG];
POINT = cell2mat(POINTS);

k_range = 1:10;

sse = zeros(length(k_range), 1);
silhouette = zeros(length(k_range), 1);
for i = 1:length(k_range)
    k = k_range(i);
    sse_temp = zeros(10, 1);
    silhouette_temp = zeros(10, 1);
    for j = 1:10
        [idx, centroid, sumd] = kmeans(POINT, k, 'Replicates', 5);
        sse_temp(j) = sum(sumd);
        silhouette_temp(j) = mean(silhouette(POINT, idx));
    end
    sse(i) = mean(sse_temp);
    silhouette(i) = mean(silhouette_temp);
end
```

The error code is

```
silhouette(POINT, idx)
```

Every time I tried to run it, it will come to this.

> Cluster_Analysis_6
> Invalid index at position 1. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

> Error in Cluster_Analysis_6 (line 17)
> silhouette_temp(j) = mean(silhouette(POINT, idx));

I made some efforts(but all failed):

1. I tried changing the variable names(eg.POINTS_R → POINT; idx → clust),to avoid the same function name and variable name.
2. I check the information about the variables.

> whos POINT
> Name           Size             Bytes  Class  Attributes
>
> POINT      19986x2             319776  double

> whos idx
> Name          Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
>
> idx       19986x1             159888  double

All the values in idx are 1

3. try to convert idx to 'int' type.
4. check the example in the Matlab Documentation page of 'silhouette'.

```
silhouette(X,clust)
```

> whos X
> Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
>
> X         20x2               320  double
>
> whos clust
> Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
>
> clust      20x1               160  double

I really want to modify the code to run it.

Comment: One possible issue is having shadowed the function `mean`  by defining an array with the same name. Type `clear mean` and see if you still get the same error.